# Proving Integrability of $sgn(\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}))$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I must show that for $f(x) = sgn(\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}))$ on $[0,1]$, that $f$ is Integrable.

I know that a function is integrable if the Upper and Lower sums of $f$ coincide. That is, if $$U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$$ where $P$ is the partition.

I let $P_n = \left \{0,\frac{1}{N}, \frac{2}{N}, \cdots , 1\right \}$. i.e., each point is evenly spaced with distance $\frac{1}{N}$. The upper and lower sums are $$U(P_n, f) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sup_{\left[\frac{i-1}{N}, \frac{i}{N}\right ]} \left ( sgn(\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})) \right ) \cdot \frac{1}{N}$$
$$L(P_n, f) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \inf_{\left[\frac{i-1}{N}, \frac{i}{N}\right ]} \left ( sgn(\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})) \right ) \cdot \frac{1}{N}$$

I'm not really sure how to find the sup/inf in the above sums . I know that $\sin$ has it's largest value at $1$ and smallest at $-1$. The sgn function makes it more simple since if $x <0$ then $sgn(x) = -1$, if $x = 0$ then $sgn(x) = 0$, and if $x>0$ then $sgn(x) = 1$.

So this means that $\sup_{\Delta x}f(x) = 1$ and $\inf_{\Delta x}f(x) = -1$ yes?

So then $$U(P_n, f) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}1 \cdot \frac{1}{N}$$ which the Harmonic Series (which is divergent). Also $$L(P_n,f) = -1 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{1}{N}$$ which is also divergent.

Since both $U$ and $L$ are divergent, that means we cannot show $U(P_n, f) - L(P_n ,f) < \epsilon$. Hence, $f$ is not Integrable.

---

Where did I mess up?

Comment: I don't get it. A function is integrable (in Lebesgue sense) if and only if its modulus is. The modulus of that function is the constant function equal to $1$ on $[0,1]$. This function is integrable. Hence, so is yours. (And incidentally if it's Lebesgue integrable but with countably many discontinuities only, it's also Riemann integrable). Perhaps you must show it using Riemann integration? Then it is just an *alternating series*.

Comment: @Frank I'm not familiar with Lebesgue Integrability. I had meant Riemann Integrability: http://people.math.sc.edu/sharpley/math554_s96/554_9/

Comment: If you form a partition whose points are the points of discontinuity, the upper and lower sums will both be the same, and equal to an alternating series (which is convergent).

Comment: From a technical standpoint, you are not stating the definition of integrable correct. You say "the partition", which is not true. The statement is:

"For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition, $P_{\epsilon}$ such that $U(f,P_{\epsilon})-L(f,P_{\epsilon})<\epsilon$."